# PHP Undefined offset error repeated

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to run a PHP script that finds all the numbers divisible by 3 or 5, dumps them into an array, and adds all the values together. However, When I try to run it, I get a number output (I don't know if it's correct or not) and several hundred errors. They start out with:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in G:\Computer Stuff\WampServer\wamp\www\findthreesandfives.php on line 18

Then the offset number increases by increments of 1-3 (randomly, I haven't seen a pattern yet). I can't figure out what's wrong. Here's my code:

```
<?php
function loop($x)
{
$a = array(); //array of values divisible by 3 or 5
$l = 0; //length of the array
$e = 0; //sum of all the values in the array
for ($i=0; $i<=$x; $i++){ //this for loop creates the array
    $n3=$i%3; 
    $n5=$i%5;
    if($n3 === 0 || $n5 === 0){
        $a[$i]=$i;
        $l++;
    }


}
for ($v=0; $v<=$l; $v++){ //this loop adds each value of the array to the total value
    $e=$e + $a[$v];
}
return $e;   
}
echo loop(1000);
?>
```

Someone please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is the following line:

```
$a[$i]=$i;
```

Should be:

```
$a[count($a)] = $i;
```

This is because the value of `$i` is always increasing, so using `$i` as your pointer will create gaps in the array's indices.  `count($a)` returns the total number of items in the given array, which also happens to be the next index.

**EDIT:** @pebbl suggested using `$a[] = $i;` as a simpler alternative providing the same functionality.

**EDIT 2:** Solving the subsequent problem the OP described in the comments:

The problem seems to be that `$l` is greater than the number of items in `$a`.  Thus, using `count($a)` in the for loop should fix your subsequent error.

Try replacing:

```
for ($v=0; $v<=$l; $v++){
```

With:

```
for ($v=0; $v<=count($a); $v++){
```

Comment: +1 for the right answer :) however it's easier to write `$a[] = $i;` in php, because php will handle incrementing the index for you.

Comment: Alright, that worked.. except now it just gives this error (and a bigger final number) Notice: Undefined offset: 468 in G:\Computer Stuff\WampServer\wamp\www\findthreesandfives.php on line 18

Comment: `$a[] = $i;` is safer if OP still want to maintain the sequence of index - no gaps

Comment: @codingbiz Safer how? `$a[count($a)] = $i;` and `$a[] = $i;` should produce the same exact results in the OP's situation and in any case where the array starts out being empty.

Comment: @user1653552 I edited my post (again) to solve the second issue you ran into.

Comment: Thanks. I only used $l because I didn't know what function would give me the length of the array.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same problem as @zsnow said. There are gaps within $a. The `if` condition allowed the gaps making the assignment skip some indexes. You can also use this

```
foreach ($a as $v){ //this loop adds each value of the array to the total value
    $e=$e + $a[$v];
}
```

should actually be

```
foreach ($a as $v){ //this loop adds each value of the array to the total value
    $e=$e + $v;
}
```

Comment: + 1 for another working answer. the foreach construct deals with situations like this wonderfully... but leaving an array with disfigured indexes like that can only cause trouble later on down the track. bad practice, imo.

Comment: alright.. I tried that, but now it gives the same pattern of errors (after I tried the first solution), but it starts at offset 468, which is where the last stream of errors ended.